# Using Laravel database sessions with SQL Server

Tags: php, sql-server, database, session, laravel

I'm using Laravel on top of SQL Server and I'm trying to store the PHP sessions in the database. I have created the sessions table per the http://laravel.com/docs/session#database-sessions but I am getting the following error when loading a page:

```
PDOException was thrown when trying to read the session data: SQLSTATE[22001]: [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]String or binary data would be truncated.
```

**Update:**

I fixed this by creating the table manually:

```
CREATE TABLE portal_sessions (
 id VARCHAR(255) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
 last_activity INT NOT NULL,
 payload TEXT NOT NULL);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that your Payload column is large enough to hold all your session data.  I'd suggest making sure that it is "VARCHAR(MAX)"

Comment: I agree, this sounds like an issue w/ column length.